# Android Fragments Not Updating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, global-variables, fragment

I am trying to create a very simple Android application that uses a FragmentPagerAdapter to swipe between three fragments. Each of the fragments contains a single EditText and has the exact same code.

The desired behavior is that when the user updates the EditText, the new value is saved to the application instance. Then, once a new fragment is selected, that new fragment should show the saved value. For some reason this is not working.

I also want the focused fragment to show the saved data when the application resumes (comes back from background). This too does not work.

I am really confused as to why something as simple as this is so difficult!

Here is my code so far:

**StackOverflowDemoApplication.java:**

```
public class StackOverflowDemoApplication extends Application {

    private ApplicationData applicationData;

    // the index of the last fragment that was displayed
    private int lastItem = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        applicationData = new ApplicationData();
    }

    public ApplicationData getApplicationData() {
        return applicationData;
    }

    public int getLastItem() {
        return lastItem;
    }

    public void setLastItem(int lastItem) {
        this.lastItem = lastItem;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // the application instance
    private StackOverflowDemoApplication application;

    // the pager adapter
    private SectionsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    // the view pager
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Save the application instance.
        application = (StackOverflowDemoApplication) getApplication();

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        pagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < pagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(pagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            // get the application data instance
            ApplicationData data = application.getApplicationData();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return SecondFragment.newInstance(data);
                case 1:
                    return FirstFragment.newInstance(data);
                case 2:
                    return ThirdFragment.newInstance(data);
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "FIRST FRAGMENT";
                case 1:
                    return "SECOND FRAGMENT";
                case 2:
                    return "THIRD FRAGMENT";
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        // load the previous fragment
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(application.getLastItem());

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        // save the last fragment we used
        application.setLastItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());

        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "FirstFragment";

    // the activity reference
    private Activity activity;

    // the application data
    private ApplicationData data;

    // the edit text
    private EditText editText;

    // are we currently loading data for this fragment?
    private boolean loadingData = false;

    public FirstFragment(ApplicationData data) {
        super();

        this.data = data;
    }

    public static FirstFragment newInstance(ApplicationData data) {
        Log.e(TAG, "New instance called");
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment(data);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Creating FirstFragment view");

        // inflate the view
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment_layout, container, false);

        // get the activity instance
        activity = getActivity();

        // the textview
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        // update the ui from the data
        updateUIFromData();

        return view;
    }

    public void updateUIFromData() {

        // we have started loading the data
        loadingData = true;

        // if there is data
        if (null != data) {

            // set the value
            if (null != data.getStringValue()) {
                editText.setText(data.getStringValue());
            }
        }

        // done loading the data
        loadingData = false;
    }

    private void updateDataFromUi() {

        data.setStringValue(editText.getText().toString());
    }

    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // if we are not loading data
            if (!loadingData) {

                // update the data from the ui
                updateDataFromUi();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to update view when fragment get visible to user as follows:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        if (visible) {
            **//Get new data and update views here**
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial, it might help you:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

You don't have to call notifyDataSetChanged() inside tabSelected callback.

Comment: Is there somewhere in that tutorial that deals with global data or sharing data between the fragments? I read it and don't see anything related to my question.

Comment: You can share data between fragments using your activity

Comment: You can add a method in your main activity to set and get data like setData(Data) …getData()
and call it inside your fragment by casting getActivity to your main activity.. it looks like MainActivity m = (MainActivity)getActivity();
then m.setData() and m.getData()
Try it and let me know what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your fragment datas in **onResumer()** like **TextView** or **EditText** ... etc. See example:

```
Oncreate....
TextView mtextview = rootview.findViewById....

@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(do some thing){
        mtextview.setText("It did something");
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```